# How to transform boost::mpl::vector into another boost::mpl::vector?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have an `boost::mpl::vector` "`myvec`", defined for example like this:

```
using myvec = boost::mpl::vector<int, double, double>;
```

Now I want to define another type, myvecex, that transforms each `myvec` member into `std::tuple` with added string. I want to get a type defined like this:

```
using myvecex = boost::mpl::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string>, 
                                   std::tuple<double, std::string>,
                                   std::tuple<double, std::string> >;
```

But I don't want to repeat myself and name all the vector members. Instead I want to define `some_smart_template` template type where I will somehow put the logic of converting each member type into a tuple.

```
using myvecex2 = some_smart_template<myvec>; 
static_assert(std::is_same<myvecex, myvecex2>::value);
```

Is it doable in C++ at all?

Answer (score 1):

Boost.MPL doesn't just give you containers, it gives you algorithms over those containers too. In this case, what you want is [`transform`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html):

```
template<
      typename Sequence
    , typename Op
    , typename In = unspecified
    >
struct transform
{
    typedef unspecified type;
};
```

The semantics are you give it a sequence and what MPL refers to as a [Lambda Expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda-expression.html) and you get out another sequence. Specifically:

```
using B = mpl::transform<A,
    std::tuple<mpl::_1, std::string>
    >::type;
```

Or at least that would work if `apply` supported variadic class templates like `std::tuple`. So you'll need to just write an operation that's either a metafunction class:

```
struct tuple_of_strings {
    template <class T>
    struct apply {
        using type = std::tuple<T, std::string>;
    };
};

using B = mpl::transform<A, tuple_of_strings>::type;
```

or a metafunction:

```
template <class T>
struct tuple_of_strings {
    using type = std::tuple<T, std::string>;
};

using B = mpl::transform<A, tuple_of_strings<_1>>::type;
```